# webform submission presave in a custom module

Tags: 7, webforms

I'm quite noob at drupal, i have a custom module with the function below:

```
function at_custom_webform_submission_presave($node, &$submission) {
// my code here
}
```

i don't know why, but it's seems that the function is not called... what's
the problem ?

I tried to use an email function php and nothing happened. and when i tried the same thing with : at_custom_user_presave, i got an email.

So that's why i'm thinking that the function is not called anymore. Before it was.

The website use 7.61 version's drupal and 7.x-4.18 version's webform.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Flush all caches, double check that At Custom Webform module is indeed enabled.

Comment: To check whether the function is running or not, you could add `drupal_set_message('Yes, it ran!');` inside the function.

Comment: Where the message will appear ?, is there a way to dump variables ? because var_dump, die doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, install & enable the **[Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel)** module. Then use `dpm($varname);` to inspect variables.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think i find why it was not triggered. 
the form was an user create form, no a webform. so that's why, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

According to your sample code,to use hook_webform_submission_presave
your module name must be "at_custom"

1. Enable Webform module
2. Enable your at_custom module
3. Put your hook under your module file: 'at_custom.module'

```
    function at_custom_webform_submission_presave($node, &$submission) {
    // your code here
    }
```

Comment: It's exactly like that but it doesn't work :(